# How to test JavaMailSender?

Tags: java, email, spring-boot, junit

I have little problem. I created MailService to send mails. When I run program, it works. All properties to email I have in `resources/application.properties`. I'm using `spring-boot-starter-mail`.

```
@Service
public class MailService {
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Autowired
    public MailService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
        this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
    }

    public void sendMail(String subject, String messageContent, String recipient)
            throws MessagingException {
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
        messageHelper.setTo(recipient);
        messageHelper.setSubject(subject);
        messageHelper.setText(messageContent);
        javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
    }
}
```

But I don't have idea how can I create test for it. I tried something like this, where I use `org.jvnet.mock-javamail:mock-javamail`, but it doesn't work:

```
public class MailServiceTest {
    private MailService mailService;

    @Mock
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mailService = new MailService(javaMailSender);
        Mailbox.clearAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void sendMailTest() throws MessagingException, IOException {
        String subject = "Some subject";
        String body = "Some contents.";
        String recipient = "test@test.com";

        mailService.sendMail(subject, body, recipient);
        List<Message> inbox = Mailbox.get(recipient);
        assertTrue(inbox.size() == 1);
        assertEquals(subject, inbox.get(0).getSubject());
        assertEquals(body, inbox.get(0).getContent());
    }
}
```

Comment: What means `but it doesn't work`?

Comment: What is `MailBox` --- where is that coming from in your test code?!

Comment: Mailbox is from `import org.jvnet.mock_javamail.Mailbox;`.

Answer (score 16):

You can test how `MimeMessage` was formed with:

```
public class EmailServiceTest {

    private EmailServiceImpl emailServiceImpl;

    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    private MimeMessage mimeMessage;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        mimeMessage = new MimeMessage((Session)null);
        javaMailSender = mock(JavaMailSender.class);
        when(javaMailSender.createMimeMessage()).thenReturn(mimeMessage);
        emailServiceImpl = new EmailService(javaMailSender);
    }

    @Test
    public void emailTest() {
        String recipient = "example@example.com"
        EmailRequest request = new EmailRequest();
        request.setRecipient(recipient);
        emailServiceImpl.send(request);
        assertEquals(recipient, mimeMessage.getRecipients(RecipientType.TO)[0].toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you are getting unit test / mocking wrong. It seems that you want to create a *unit* test; but expect the results of a *integration* test.

What you can do with a unit test here:

- provide a **mocked** JavaMailSender (as you already)
- use **verify** on that mock later on

In other words: you are mocking the actual sending of a mail. Thus you can't expect that a mail will show up somewhere!

The only thing possible: ensure that the method calls you expect to see actually take place. But that basically leads you to write a test case that simply "re-implements" your production code using verify calls. That isn't too helpful.

Probably you should rather look into a *real* **integration** test here. Send a **real** email; and check a real inbox if that mail shows up there.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have little problem. I don't know how to verify this mock.

Comment: I found in Google how to use verify on mock and it works :D Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are very welcome. Please consider accepting my answer then.

Answer (score 3):

I use `Mockito` to mock a `JavaMailSender` bean and instantiate it in a class annotated with `@Configuration` that runs only using a **test** profile:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;

@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class EmailServiceTest {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSender javaMailSender = mock(JavaMailSender.class);
        when(javaMailSender.createMimeMessage()).thenReturn(new MimeMessage((Session) null));
        return javaMailSender;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use greenmail http://www.icegreen.com/greenmail instead of mocking a email server

```
@Test
public void test_MyMailSend() {
    GreenMail greenMail = new GreenMail(ServerSetupTest.SMTP_IMAP);
    try {
        greenMail.start();
        //your class method call goes her 
        assertTrue(greenMail.waitForIncomingEmail(5000, 1));
        //Retrieve using GreenMail API
        Message[] messages = greenMail.getReceivedMessages();
        final String subject = messages[0].getSubject();
        final String msgContent = messages[0].getContent().toString();
        assertEquals(1, messages.length);
        assertEquals(subject, MyClass.SUPPORT_SUBJECT);
        assertEquals(messages[0].getAllRecipients()[0].toString(), MyClass.SUPPORT_ADDRESS);
        assertEquals(messages[0].getFrom()[0].toString(), MyClass.FROM_EMAIL);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        greenMail.stop();
    }
}
```